# Which Java Version required for Junit 4.1

Tags: java, junit, version, cucumber-junit

Working with Cucumber FrameWork, Need to know Which Java Version required for Junit 4.1 version

Comment: Have you tried google?

Answer (score 0):

JUnit 4.x need at least Java 1.5 (one of the reasons is that JUnit 4 uses Annotations, which were introduced in Java 1.5)